# Suggested edits feature broken for tag wikis

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

It appears that the new suggested edits feature was only partially implemented with tag wikis. I experienced this problem on SuperUser, but suspect it's a system-wide issue with the engine, so am bringing it up on MSO.

- I was given the option to edit the tag wikis for tags which already had one, but upon submitting a proposed edit, was greeted with an error screen every time.
- Tags which do not yet have a tag wiki have no means by which to propose a new one entirely.

I'm not sure to what extent this is expected behavior and to what extent this is a bug, but it's certainly not behaving consistently.

Comment: I have not unlocked it for "creating new wikis" will dig through and see why suggesting an edit is playing up

Comment: @waffles, I tried again on another tag (it was google-chrome before, this time microsoft-excel) and this time it didn't show an error, but nor did it show any indication that any sort of change had been made or even suggested - everything looked exactly the same. Can you look at the tag wiki for microsoft-excel on SU and see if there's a pending edit or if it never went through even?

Comment: yes the indication you made a change on tag wikis is broken, I can confirm that

Comment: aha this is the second weird one I have seen, http://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/28 clearly this is not your intended edit?

Comment: @waffles, no it is not. It looks like the original text shown is from the "excerpt" and the edited text is from the original text in the description. Neither is my actual proposed edit.

Comment: Furthermore, I am being shown buttons for "reject" and "accept" edit, even though it was my own edit, which I doubt is by design.

Comment: More info: I just received a notification that I had received the tag editor badge for "excel", and yet my actual edit was not shown, at least not in its entirety.

Comment: @nhinkle ... I just deployed the fix ... can you try submitting a few more wiki edits (keep in mind, creating new wikis is still blocked out)

Comment: @waffles, I submitted my suggested edits for [google-chrome](http://superuser.com/tags/google-chrome/info) and [microsoft-excel](http://superuser.com/tags/excel/info). It looks to me like the suggestions went through successfully.

Comment: @nhinkle ... yes, looks fine to me http://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/31

Comment: @waffles, one more little issue: on the page you just linked, it said you approved the edit, but on the page itself, it still says "This edit will only be visible to you until it is peer reviewed".

Comment: @waffles And upon further checking, the edits _do not_ appear when not signed in. So even though it says on the status page that it was approved, it looks like it wasn't.

Comment: aha ... I know what it is @nhinkle .... I just approved half of your edit, wikis are made out of 2 posts ... when the second part is approved the message will go away

Comment: Ah, OK. Let me know when that's done and I'll check that everything looks right. Thanks again @waffles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some serious bugs there, however I think I sorted them out now. Will be deployed shortly